# How to add a long and preserve precision when printing

Tags: java, long-integer

How do I preserve precision in my `sum` output? I think that what is happening is that the precision is exactly the same, but one option chooses to round.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final long seconds = 1637208584L;
        final long micro_of_second = 795307;
        final long sum = seconds + micro_of_second;
        System.out.println("seconds + micro_of_second: " + seconds + micro_of_second);
        System.out.println("sum:                       " + sum);
        System.out.println("equal?:                    " + (sum == seconds + micro_of_second));
    }
}
```

### Output

```bash
seconds + micro_of_second: 1637208584795307
sum:                       1638003891
equal?:                    true
```

Comment: "*`System.out.println("seconds + micro_of_second: " + seconds + micro_of_second);`*" - What do you think that line does?

Comment: Please check this for the details: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1

Comment: By the way, tracking date-time as a count from an epoch reference is error-prone and inherently ambiguous, making it difficult to debug. I suggest you use objects instead, from *java.time* classes, and serialize to text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. This has been addressed extensively on Stack Overflow, so search to learn more. `Instant.ofEpochSecond( 1_637_208_584L ).plus( 795_307L , ChronoUnit.MICROS ).toString()` … `2021-11-18T04:09:44.795307Z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here isn't with precision its with the line

```
System.out.println("seconds + micro_of_second: " + seconds + micro_of_second);
```

this line implicitly converts `seconds` and `micro_of_second` to a string and concatenates them together.

so the result you are seeing is actually:

"seconds + micro_of_second: " + "1637208584" + "795307"

what you want to do is evaluate the integer addition before adding it to the string. you can accomplish this by changing that line to

```
System.out.println("seconds + micro_of_second: " + (seconds + micro_of_second));
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, expressions are evaluated left to right. Thus

```
"seconds + micro_of_second: " + seconds + micro_of_second
```

Is semantically identical to

```
("seconds + micro_of_second: " + seconds) + micro_of_second
```

The expression

```
"seconds + micro_of_second: " + seconds
```

evaluates to a `String`, where the (base 10) `String`-representation of seconds (`"1637208584"`) is appended to the `String "seconds + micro_of_second: "`. resulting in the `String "seconds + micro_of_second: 1637208584"`.
Then, the (base 10) `String`-representation of `micro_of_second` (`795307`) is appended to the `String "seconds + micro_of_second: 1637208584"`, resulting in the String `seconds + micro_of_second: 1637208584795307`.

By contrast, `seconds + micro_of_second` adds both values (`1637208584 + 795307`), evaluating to the `long`-value `1638003891`.

If we want to first add both `long`s, we can enforce the evaluation order by introducing parentheses:

```
"seconds + micro_of_second: " + (seconds + micro_of_second)
```

This will evaluate to the `String "seconds + micro_of_second: 1638003891"`.

Alternatively, if we want to get the total amount of microseconds, we need to multiply the value of `seconds` with `1_000_000L` before adding `micro_of_second` (since there are `1_000_000` microseconds in a second):

```
"micros: " + (seconds * 1_000_000L + micro_of_second)
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/zqJSI7)

---

As an aside: In Java, variable names should be written in `camelCase` instead of `snake_case` (`micro_of_second` -> `microOfSecond`)